# app.get is not working for base route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am an absolutely newby in node.js and I try to create a new project via this technology. I use express framework but on the start I have a little trouble. I have solved this trouble with workaround but I have a question for next behavior:
My **app.js**

```
var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes/index')
  , routes = require('./routes/login');

var app = module.exports = express.createServer(); 
console.log(app.env);
// Configuration

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});


app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));
});

app.configure('production', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

// Routes

app.use( function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.url == '/') {
        res.render('index', { title: 'Express!' })
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
//app.get('/', routes.index);

app.get('/login', routes.login);


app.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log("Express server listening on port %d in %s mode", app.address().port, app.settings.env);
});
```

In a block **// Routes** you can see **app.use** and **app.get**. If I try to use **app.get** instead of **app.use** I get error **"cannot get /"**. I tried to put index.html file to my public folder. But fot "/" route I everytime got this file, not render of index.js.

app.get('/login', routes.login); - is work fine, but something wrong with "/" route. I dont want to leave my code in this state, please, help me understand this behavior.

Thank in advance.

Comment: you are redeclaring `routes`, just change the variable name.

Comment: Thanks. But how to write beautiful code? I have everytime to duplicate pairs: routes = require('./routes') -> app.get('/', routes.index); ....... routes1 = require('./routes/login')  -> app.get('/login', routes1.login); etc.. ?

Comment: There are many modularization patterns you may use. For example, you might include all your individual routes in a common `routes` module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the user PA. mentioned, the reason your code never finds the `/` url, is because you are redeclaring your routes variable:

```
var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes/index')  // first declaration of 'routes'
  , routes = require('./routes/login'); // re-declaration of 'routes'
```

This makes your first routes declaration (the declaration that was pointing to /index) unreachable by your code, which is why you get the error "cannot get /", because your routes variable only points to ./routes/login.

There are a few ways you can fix this to clean up your code:

**1. Assign different variables for the different routes:**

```
var express = require('express')
    , index = require('./routes/index')  
    , login = require('./routes/login');
```

**- 0R -**

**2. Put multiple functions in the routes file:**

```
// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// in your routes/index file

exports.index = function(req, res){
   res.render('index', { title: 'Index Page' });
};

exports.login = function(req, res){
   res.render('login', { title: 'Login Page' });
};


// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// in your app.js file

// import your 'routes' functions from your 'routes' file 
var express = require('express')
      , routes = require('./routes/')  


// now use your routes functions like this:
app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/login', routes.login);
```

**- OR -**

In a large application, or for better code maintainability, you may want to break up your different routing functions into different files (instead of putting all your routing functions in one file, like the example above), so using the express default setup as an example, they are placing their `user` functions and their `index` functions in the routes folder this like:

```
routes /
   user.js
   index.js
```

Then, they setup their application like this:

```
var routes = require('./routes');
var user = require('./routes/user');
```

And call these functions like this:

```
app.get('/', routes.index); // calls the "index" function inside the routes/index.js
app.get('/users', user.list); // calls the "list" function inside the routes/user.js file
```

Hope this helps.

Quick tip: `app.use()` is used to create middleware, which is a function that will get called on each request in your application, giving you, the developer, access to the request object `req`, and the response object `res`, and the power to change, or enhance your application somehow. The ability to "act in the middle of a request" is a powerful feature, and the reason why it was working for you in your original example is because your `app.use()` middleware was getting called when the request for `/` was being called, even though your app couldn't find `/`, which was lost when you re-declared the `routes` variable, you were still making a request to `/`, which your app.use() was able to see (because middleware gets called on EVERY request, even the "bad" ones), so your middleware was still seeing the [invalid] request to `/` and acting like this:

```
// This middleware will get called on every request, 
// even on the invalid request for '/'
app.use( function(req, res, next) {

    // this line of code will see that the 
    // request is for "/" and fire
    if (req.url == '/') {
        // the page now appears to render, because you are forcing the
        // res.render code inside of your middleware, which isn't always
        // recommended, but it is working for you in this example
        // because its the only place in your example that can do anything
        // when the '/' request is made
        res.render('index', { title: 'Express!' })
    } else {
        // this is common middleware design pattern, the next()
        // function tells the express framework to "move on to the next function"
        // in the middleware stack
        next();
    }
});
```